# insetting a linebreak at cursorposition in an EXCEL cell using ENTER

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way of making a line break when your cursor is positioned somewhere in the text of a cell (that you are editing)? Only using **[ENTER]** and **NOT** [Alt][ENTER].

I tried by **VBA** and, in the (advanced) properties, let the selection stay in the same cell after [ENTER] is pressed. Without the right solution:

Initializing the Open event in the **ThisWorkBook** module, to call the makeLineBreak-method whenever pressing the [ENTER]:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "~", "makeLineBreak"
End Sub
```

The method to be called when ENTER is pressed (placed in a module):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub makeLineBreak()
    SendKeys "%{ENTER}", True
End Sub
```

BUT, already when the ENTER is pressed, the cell is not in edit mode anymore and there's of course no line break where I intended.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Invoking a macro *while in edit mode*?

Comment: Did you try inserting `Chr(10)` ?

Comment: The short answer (to "Is there any way") would be ... no.  You can't run a macro while in edit mode.  Unless Excel provides an option to change the behaviour of the Enter key while editing a cell, I think you are out of luck.  (And, even if you were able to do it, just think what would happen when the user pressed Enter to signify that they had finished editing the cell.)

Comment: @YowE3K. You would use the arrows or the TAB to change to the next cell. But if ENTER="finish editing for sure 100%", then I can conclude: no solution!

Comment: @Mat's Mug. Yes, I presume that it is the only way of accomplishing the task ..

Comment: You can't do that. You have a hook to run some code just before the cell is exited, not as every character gets typed.